# How to quietly prompt user to use two finger swipe?

Tags: intuition, swipe

I was helping make an app for a class I am in and we stumbled across a small problem.

We have a full page carousel:

[image]

And for development reasons (the carousel's horizontal swipe would interfere with the detection of vertical swipe) we decided to use a 2 finger swipe up to exit this and the next page slides in from the bottom.

**What is an example of presenting this action to the user?**

I haven't seen anything online about it. I can only think to present them an obnoxious GIF of the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this can be solved with the swipe icon, many apps show its when its not that intuitive to use
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two primary ways to solve this:

**Page Indicator:**

If there are `X` number of pages, then put `X` dots somewhere persistently on the screen with the active page highlighted. The orientation of the dots will imply how the user must swipe to get to the next / previous page.

[image]

**Buttons:**

Snapchat solves this problem with buttons. If there are "next" and "previous" page buttons, the user will intuitively user them for navigation. After seeing the next page slide into view, the user will likely infer that they can use swipe gestures as well as the buttons to navigate.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to get the user to use **2 fingers**

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question. I realize this does not answer your question, but I would suggest figuring out a way to solve your core problem which is not "how to convey a 2 finger swipe" but instead "how to make my application behave as the user expects". Again, sorry for misreading.